# .NET replacing values where keys match

Tags: .net, list, replace, match, intersect

This is a simple question. I have two lists ListA and ListB they are both full of the same type of objects with keys, but everything else (besides key) can be different, the size the values etc..... I want to replace the values in ListA with values from ListB where they match (without O(m*n), since I could do it easily with loop inside loop) and the values that do exist in ListB but don't exist in ListA should be added to ListA, this can be two operations I don't mind but I want to keep the difficulty below O(n^2) or O(m*n)

I tried using intersect but I am not sure how to move on from there I can get rows that match, but how to replace add them... Is beyond me.

Comment: Well, you might want to use the Dictionary's O(1) lookups. Create a Dictionary out of one of the lists and then loop through the other list and check whether the key exists in the dictionary

Comment: @Fabjan could you elaborate ? I see that you edited it, thanks for the answer I will check it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your class overrides `Equals` and `GetHashCode`(to compare the `Key`) or/and implements `IEqualityComparer<YourClass>`, you can use `Intersect` and `Except`. However, in this case you should use a (left-outer-)`Join` which is also a set based approach:

```
var query =
    from b in listB
    join a  in listA on b.Key equals a.Key into ba
    from a_join in ba.DefaultIfEmpty()
    select (OnlyInB: a_join == null, A: a_join, B: b);
    

foreach(var x in query)
{
    if(x.OnlyInB)
    {
        listA.Add(x.B);
    }
    else
    {
        CompareAndTransferProperties(x.A, x.B);
    }
}
```

and a method `CompareAndTransferProperties` which does  what it name suggests:

```
private static void CompareAndTransferProperties(MyClass a, MyClass b)
{
    // your task ...
}
```

Comment: This seems to be working nicely, just quick additional question, in CompareAndTransferProperties... I want to swap everything and there are over 50 properties... they are exactly the same object typeWhat would be a good way to just basically say

Object A = Object b ? ICopiable ? 

Right now I found this solution:                                                              

            foreach (PropertyInfo property in typeof(User).GetProperties().Where(p => p.CanWrite))
            {
                property.SetValue(a, property.GetValue(b, null), null);
            }

Comment: @DemiGod: provide a factory method in `MyClass`: `public static MyClass Copy(MyClass other)`. There you should use the boilerplate code to assign all properties manually. Reflection is slow and also not safe, it's hidden magic that i would prevent, but up to you.